# TensorFlow Docker does not have python3-tk package

Tags: docker, matplotlib, tensorflow

I am new to TensorFlow. I installed TensorFlow via Docker on MacBook Pro. When I run a short codes which imports matplotlib.pyplot. I received error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "timegradient.py", line 3, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 113, in <module>

    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 60, in pylab_setup
    [backend_name], 0)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    raise ImportError(str(msg) + ', please install the python3-tk package')

ImportError: No module named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package
```

I could not find python3.5 folder inside usr/lib or /usr/local/lib. I installed tinker package for Mac OS from https://www.activestate.com/. But it did not help to solve problem. It seems I could not work with matplotlib inside TensorFlow docker container.

Very much appreciate any help on this.

Comment: for the time being, install all the required package manually inside the docker; Then you can make use of 'docker commit' to create the new image of the running docker and you can use that image eventually for further stuff.

Comment: @Viswesn I installed matplotlib and it still show the same error on Mac OS. The final error message [RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework.] lead me to this page: http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend. I can fix this problem just by adding these two lines: import matplotlib,
matplotlib.use('PS'). It says it is backend conflict problem on Mac OS.

Comment: After fixing the issue on the Docker instance make sure that it is working perfectly fine and then go for docker save command to create a new image.

Comment: I dont need docker save. Btw when I tried matplotlib.use('TkAgg'), it still showed the same error. But when I used pip to install missing packages such as matplotlib, it says it already had it. When i use pip to install python3-tk, it says there is not such that package. If you have experience with tensorflow docker on mac os, kindly advise me. Thanks.

Comment: My point is that when i created new folder, created VM for python3, installed manually all packages, and tried matplotlib.use('TkAgg'), then it worked on Mac OS. However, when i tried to install missing packages inside docker, as you advised, it did not work.

Comment: They say that, currently, graphs created by matplotlib in tensorflow docker on Mac OS can only be seen by jupyter notebook. It cannot be seen in shell or terminal. If we install everything manually on local machine, then it will be no problem. I have not yet tried Dockerfile show I dont know how it will be. FYI. Thanks.